# joi setting boolean default value based on another field

Tags: reactjs, joi

Suppose I have this object with two keys, a and b. a is string and b is a boolean. What I am looking for is if a is blank then b has a default value of true if not false.

This schema

```
Joi.object({
  'a': Joi.string(),
  'b': Joi.alternatives()
    .when('a', {
      is: '',
      then: Joi.boolean().default(true),
      otherwise: Joi.boolean().default(false)
    })
})
```

with the object throws an error "Cannot combine alternatives with boolean"

```
{ 
 a: '',
 b: false
}
```

This may fall outside of what Joe is meant for but I am curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[.default()](https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/master/API.md#anydefaultvalue) can accept a function with the arguments (parent, helpers), with parent you can access any object value and do something like this:

```
const schema = Joi.object({
    a: Joi.string().allow(''),
    b: Joi.boolean().default((parent) => parent.a == '')
})

// Object {value: Object {a: "", b: true}}
schema2.validate({ a: '' })
// Object {value: Object {a: "", b: false}}
schema2.validate({ a: 'aaa' })
```